# How to determine if sampling is representative to population

Tags: sampling, sample, population

Is there any coefficient or some metric that will tell how well sample reflect the population?

Comment: Do you have any independent information about the population? How were the data sampled?

Comment: You should take a look at the literature on propensity scores.  That literature is filled with methods for assessing whether or not a sample looks like it may have been drawn at random from a broader population.  The work by Rubin, 1983 is the seminal work in this area.

Comment: @StatsStudent should this be [Rubin 1973](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2529684?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Truth be told the 1973 work and 1983 works are both important.